# Is there a PressThis that doesn't hotlink?

Tags: plugins, blog

What are some plugins or alternatives to the PressThis function?

I want to use the PressThis bookmarklet to quickly blog about what I see online, but every time I do and include an image, it hotlinks to the image from the site I'm blogging about.

That's bad, because I don't want to tax the site I'm writing about. I don't want to use a full-sized image. And I don't want the image to be broken on my site if the site I'm writing about to goes down.

Comment: Another thing to think about is using someone else's copyrighted image.  Most news and other sources including Associated Press do not allow any use of their images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PressThis bookmarklet does upload images to the wp uploads folder that you add to the article. Basically in the PressThis window go to the 'Add' menu and click on 'Insert an Image' icon.

It will populate thumbnails of images found on the web page you are on. Click on the image you want to include in your post and that will open up a small window with the image you selected. As well there's an empty Description field and just above that field - on the right click on 'Insert Image' and it will insert it in your post.

Now this will insert the image AND wrap a hyperlink to it to the web page that you got it from but once saved it will upload that image to your site.

Comment: I just did it on this page, with your Gravatar. This is the code that was generated. It doesn't seem to be uploading the image to my site. Am I missing something?
<a href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50124/is-there-a-pressthis-that-doesnt-hotlink"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9219b657a24568b5e32b5c051ab45093?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="" /></a></p>

Comment: Gravatar is a dynamically loaded image and you'll get this with these types of images as the source url will not end with a file extension - ie: .gif, .jpg, or .png. So, PressThis will not understand this and will leave it as is.

Try it on an ordinary image in an article. It will work. If not, try a fresh install of wordpress and try again... it should work. If not - check to see your uploads folders permission is writable.

Comment: I hate to say it, but the same thing happened on other photos that I imported.

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using and which browser? Want to try to see if I can replicate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for asking. It's on both Chrome and Safari. I made this video to show what I'm seeing:
http://youtu.be/0fcLbH7QaKg

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes... you are missing one step - Save to Draft or Publish. Then it will save and upload the image to your media library and it will attach it to the post :)

Comment: oh george.n you're incredible! That did it! I've had this problem for years and you solved it! Thank you for all the patience. How do I give you the bounty? Or anything to show how grateful I am to you?

Comment: No need. I'm glad I was able to help :)